# How to condense multiple different if statements (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, dictionary

I am making a quiz in the style of 20 Questions. It uses a text file to create a dictionary with codes relating to answers. At the moment it only has 5 questions which is no where near enough to be accurate with 'guesses' but already it is looking messy and hard to understand

CODES.txt Example Contents:

a1000,A Book

a1111,A Saucepan

Code:

```
File = open("CODES.txt","r")
CODES = { }

for line in File:
    x = line.split(",")
    a = x[0]
    b = x[1]
    c = len(b)-1
    b = b[0:c]
    CODES[a] = b

print("Think of anything: \n")

Q1 = str(input("Is it a) An Object, b) A Person, c) A Film: "))
if Q1 == "a":
    Q2 = input("Is it hard: ")
    if Q2 == "0":
        Q3 = input("Is it light: ")
        if Q3 == "0":
            Q4 = input("Is it smaller than your head: ")
            if Q4 == "0":
                Q5 = input("Is it square: ")
            elif Q4 == "1":
                Q5 = input("Is it circular: ")
        elif Q3 == "1":
            Q4 = input("Is it bigger than your head: ")
            if Q4 == "0":
                Q5 = input("Is it square: ")
            elif Q4 == "1":
                Q5 = input("Is it circular: ")
    elif Q2 == "1":
        Q3 = input("Is it heavy: ")
        if Q3 == "0":
            Q4 = input("Is it smaller than your head: ")
            if Q4 == "0":
                Q5 = input("Is it square: ")
            elif Q4 == "1":
                Q5 = input("Is it circular: ")
        elif Q3 == "1":
            Q4 = input("Is it bigger than your head: ")
            if Q4 == "0":
                Q5 = input("Is it square: ")
            elif Q4 == "1":
                Q5 = input("Is it circular: ")

CCODE = str(Q1+Q2+Q3+Q4+Q5)

if CCODE in CODES:
    print("You are thinking of " + CODES[CCODE])
else:
    NV = str(input("You have outsmarted me. What were you thinking of: "))
    File = open("CODES.txt","a")
    File.write((CCODE+","+NV+"\n"))
    File.close()
```

How would i make the question segment, the If-Statements easier to read/understand. Currently i have loads of embedded ones and it only consists of 5 questions each with 2/3 answers.

Comment: Maybe setting your question structure on a dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

I will try to give you some thoughts but not solve your problem directly:

- Think about what you can put into a separate function. This would make sense  for statements that are repeated several times.
- You can very easily return strings from Python functions. Then you can use the returned strings as keys for a dictionary.
- Also there is the possibility to return functions from other functions as everything is an object in Python.

  For example `Q4 = input("Is it smaller than your head: ")` could be turned into a statement like
  `obj_size = ask_size()` with outputs `"small"`, `"big"`.

I hope that helps you :)